# Passing slices to a function

Tags: go

I have some confusion regarding passign slices to function. Here is what I have readed:

[image]

Here are what I have understood: slice is a structure with a pointer to real data; when we are passing a slice to a function, we just copy a pointer, but the function is working with the same data as original function.

Here is my code:

```
type Example struct {
    A int
    B string
}

func foo(d []Example) {
    for _, e := range d {
        e.B = "bye"
    }
}

func main() {

    a := Example{}
    a.A = 10
    a.B = "hello"

    b := Example{}
    b.A = 10
    b.B = "hello"

    var c []Example
    c = append(c, a)
    c = append(c, b)

    foo(c)

    for _, e := range c {
        fmt.Println(e.B)
    }
}
```

I have passed slice of structs to a function and have changed the struct in the function. Why I have old values in the main function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's a slice of structs, not a slice of pointers to structs. When you execute:

```
for _, e := range d
```

Inside the loop, `e` is *a copy of* the element from the slice; modifying it does not modify what's in the slice. If `d` were a `[]*Example`, it would work as you expected: https://play.golang.org/p/4ZgLETpq6d0

Note in particular that this has nothing at all to do with slices. If it were:

```
func foo(d Example) {
    d.B = "bye"
}
```

You would run into the same problem: the function is modifying *a copy of* the struct, so the caller's copy is unaffected by what happens inside the function.

Another potential solution without using pointers would be to modify the values *inside the slice*, rather than in a copy of the element:

```
func foo(d []Example) {
    for i := range d {
        d[i].B = "bye"
    }
}
```

Working example of this style: https://play.golang.org/p/_UJGU0XqaUO